# “Assé” instead of “assez” - is this a valid word?

Tags: orthographe

A native French person recently wrote to me, saying "assé" instead of assez (meaning "enough")...

Is this normal in informal writing?

Comment: Believe me, native speakers of every language, not just English, make mistakes. :) For a while I practiced French by reading some of the posts on [psychologies.com](http://forum.psychologies.com/psychologiescom/Le-quotidien-dans-le-couple/liste_sujet-1.htm), all written by Francophones. If you ever want a handbook for how not to spell, just poke your head in there. But I did learn a lot of short forms in common use on the Internet!

Comment: Maybe your correspondent has a Walloon connection: …. [1870 Bulletin de la Société de Littérature Wallone](https://books.google.com/books?id=ves_AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA193&dq=%22ass%C3%A9%22#v=onepage&q=%22ass%C3%A9%22&f=false) … [1852 Dictionnaire wallon-français](https://books.google.com/books?id=JX45AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=ass%C3%A9+ou+assez&source=bl&ots=Rj8FeG2cvG&sig=C_cvvvFBBLy7rkGlHHPeTtk_z7c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig8oqhptrYAhWIUd8KHR0LBygQ6AEIdjAL#v=onepage&q=ass%C3%A9%20assez&f=false)  [online Dictionnaire wallon-français](http://chanae.walon.org/lh/wa/dic/index.php) (enter "assé")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling shortcuts are common in textos/SMSs, and one that will require less characters seems to be quite welcome in general. So one could think ***assé*** could be a quicker way to spell ***assez***, but it is likely not the case, because typing an accentuated letter on most touch-screen devices takes longer than typing two letters *(hold the finger for a moment on the letter you want an accent on, then slide the finger to select the accent you want, then let go)*.

Most devices also have an auto-complete option that will let people choose ***assez***, which again makes it quicker to type than ***assé***.

Also, ***assez*** is common enough a word for someone to know its spelling, unless one actively wants to disregard it, for a stylistic purpose or other.

I haven’t really been exposed to ***assé***, and I suspect it is rather rare, even in informal texts. It really doesn’t have much to promote itself: it is incorrect and longer to type, and it’s not even introducing a possible alternate pronunciation.

On the other hand, as pointed out in the comments below, one might expect ***AC*** as an abbreviation of ***assez*** in SMS.

Comment: In SMS speak, I'd rather simply expect ***AC***

Comment: @jlliagre Good point! It still won't make "assé" common, though. And that was the question. May I use your comment in the answer?

Comment: Of course you can!

Answer (score 4):

I think that this person is not very good at spelling. The correct form is:

> Assez